# Create classes for body tag using javascript

Tags: javascript, class, dynamic

I have multiple pages that need consistent `<body>` classes, plus a unique class per page.  I would like to set these values dynamically to eliminate managing constant classes on page level.

The ideal solution would start with an empty `<body>` tag, where the javascript created will allow me to inject classes when needed. The potential properties are

```
tabClass, catClass, secClass, pageClass
```

Where any combination of these can exist, including none at all.
Can anyone help me with this? I am at the beginning stages of learning Javascript so I apologize now for my ignorance. Thanks.

The ideal output would be:

```
bodyClasses = (tabClass, catClass, secClass)
pageClass = (pageClass)
```

Comment: So, your problem is assigning classes to DOM elements or what exactly?

Comment: Might help - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.className

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you need some functions like:

```
var util = util || {};

util.trim = function(s) {
  return s.replace(/(^\s+)|(\s+$)/g,'').replace(/\s+/g,' ');
}

util.dom = util.dom || {};

util.dom.hasClassName = function(el, cName) {
    if (typeof el == 'string') el = document.getElementById(el);

    var re = new RegExp('(^|\\s+)' + cName + '(\\s+|$)');
    return el && re.test(el.className);
}

util.dom.addClassName = function(el, cName) {

    if (typeof el == 'string') el = document.getElementById(el);

    if (!util.dom.hasClassName(el, cName)) {
        el.className = util.trim(el.className + ' ' + cName);
    }
}

util.dom.addClassNames = function(el) {

    if (typeof el == 'string') el = document.getElementById(el);

    for (var i=1, iLen=arguments.length; i<iLen; i++) {
      util.dom.addClassName(el, arguments[i]);
    }
}

util.dom.removeClassName = function(el, cName) {

    if (typeof el == 'string') el = document.getElementById(el);

    if (util.dom.hasClassName(el, cName)) {
        var re = new RegExp('(^|\\s+)' + cName + '(\\s+|$)','g');
        el.className = util.trim(el.className.replace(re, ''));
    }
}
```

And use them like:

```
var body = document.body;
util.dom.addClassName(body, 'tabClass');
```

The addClassNames function takes multiple arguments:

```
util.dom.addClassNames(body, 'tabClass', 'catClass', 'secClass');
```

Note that if the element already has the class, it isn't added a second time.

Answer (score 2):

In a script element somewhere after the opening `<body>` tag:

```
var commonClasses = "tabClass catClass secClass",
    currentPageClasses;

/* Your own logic here to determine what classes apply to the
   current page, add them to currentPageClasses variable */

document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].className += " "
                                                   + commonClasses
                                                   + " "
                                                   + currentPageClasses;
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nnnnnn/FhMP8/